# Cypher query: find path by relationship properties

Tags: neo4j, cypher

My problem is very close to this topic: [Cypher query: Finding all paths between two nodes filtered by relationship properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14104682/cypher-query-finding-all-paths-between-two-nodes-filtered-by-relationship-prope) but what I'm trying to do is to find path which has increasing value of relationship property along the path. So in that previos topics example solution paths (from A to D) would be:

**A->D** and **A->B->D**

I used solution from previous topic

```
START a=node(1), d=node(4) 
MATCH p=a-[r:ACTIVATES*..]->d 
WITH head(relationships(p)) as r1,p
WHERE all(r2 in relationships(p) 
      where r2.temperature > r1.temperature) 
return p;
```

and it works for this example. Problem is when there is path with more then 2 relationships, for example:

```
    activates:50      activates:70      activates:60
(A)-------------->(B)-------------->(C)-------------->(D)
```

this path unfortunately matches too.

Is there way how to write this query in cypher or I'll have to use gremlin instead?

Thanks for any suggestion.

**Update:** What I need is some construction like (in pseudo programing language):

```
WITH head(relationships(p)) as r1,p
FOREACH(r2 in tail(relationships(p)):
    r1.temperature < r2.temperature, r1 = r2)
```

but in cypher if it's posible.

Answer (score 2):

This one worked in my example

```
START a=node(1), d=node(4) 
MATCH p=a-[r:ACTIVATES*..]-d 
WITH head(relationships(p))as r1,last(relationships(p))as r2,p
WHERE all(r3 in relationships(p) 
      where r2.temperature > r1.temperature AND NOT r3.temperature < r1.temperature) 
return p;
```

**Update:** Is there any way to do that with node properties?

Comment: Hi. Thank you for the answer. But this won't work for me. This actualy matches **(A)--50-->(B)--70-->(C)--60-->(D)** but I need to match only **(A)--50-->(B)--60-->(C)--70-->(D)**

Comment: Theoretically it is possible to add special nodes with this properties. But in my case it will lead to extreme large and complicated graph (now my graph has 100k+ of nodes and I counted that this change would lead to hundred 100M+ of nodes)

Comment: If node properties can be used for incremental property path finding te you can add to your existing nodes the property value of the relationship wit something like this `foreach(r in relationships(p):
FOREACH(x in nodes(p):SET x.value=r.value))`.