# finding shortest path that excludes particular edges?

Tags: python, graph, neo4j, py2neo

I'm using Py2neo, but that probably doesn't matter since this will most likely need to be done by writing a Cypher query.

Essentially, I want to find a shortest path in a *subgraph*, where the subgraph is most of the whole graph but with a very small fraction (a millionth or less) of the edges removed.

For example, say I have nodes A, B, and C, and edges (A->B), (A->C), (B->C).  Of course, the shortest path from A to C is via the direct connection.  But if I wanted to find the shortest path that *doesn't* use that edge, it would have to be A B C.

Also, this will be something that a user can specify in a multi-user (web) application.  So I can't really alter the database itself...if that weren't an issue, I could maybe create a property on edges "allow: true/false" and set it to false, but that would mess with application behavior for all current users.

A variation on that would be to have "disallow: sessionID1, sessionID230, sessionID1010", i.e. actually store which application sessions want to exclude that edge in the edge itself, but this also does not seem ideal.

Of course, I could actually implement the BFS in python by getting nodes as needed from neo4j and keeping them on a queue instead of having neo4j do the search, but surely that would be much slower, right?

Any thoughts?  Thanks

EDIT: request to see code.

Below is how I'm currently getting the shortest path between two nodes that I first look up in an index. Now image there's also a list of edges (that is, unique relationships) that have to be ignored in the shortest path search.

```
from py2neo import neo4j

g = neo4j.GraphDatabaseService()

def shortest_path(a, b):
    a = g.get_indexed_node("worddex", "word", a)
    b = g.get_indexed_node("worddex", "word", b)
    if not a and b: return None
    query_string = "START beginning=node(%d), end=node(%d) MATCH p = shortestPath(beginning-[*..100]-end) RETURN p" % (a._id, b._id)
    result = neo4j.CypherQuery(g, query_string).execute()
    if not len(result): return None
    p = result[0].p
    ret = []
    for node in p.nodes:
        ret.append(node["word"])
    return ret
```

EDIT 2: example console: http://console.neo4j.org/r/3c1rgn

It's easy to find a shortest "friendship path" between any two people, but what if we want to find a shortest friendship path that *doesn't* involve a particular friendshi rel (or particular set of friendship rels), but without modifying the database first? e.g., we want to find the shortest friendship path from bob to joe wherein we momentarily assume bob and joe aren't friends themselves, nor are alice and janet.

Comment: It's a bit broad your question, it is almost certainly better to form the query and use the Neo4 engine to perform the calculations rather than pull the data out of the database into a graph structure and analyse using python

Comment: @EdChum I figured that would be the case.  So my question is, in light of that, how can I accomplish my goal using the Neo4j engine?

Answer (score 2):

Can't you use the '[allShortestPaths](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/query-match.html#_shortest_path)' option in cypher and use it to reject paths which contain some specific rel types or node types using python? I guess it would depend on how and on what parameters you want to restrict results, and whether they can be detected using only what cypher returns to python in the form of a path.

Another way to do it would be to instruct Cypher to return ALL POSSIBLE PATHS from a node to another (some smart restrictions can be applied within the query itself here).

Then based on the collection of paths Cypher returns, you can run some Python code to reject paths which contain, say, a particular rel type or a node type that you are not interested in. You will then be left with a collection of possible paths fitting your acceptance criteria (except the shortest condition). You can then simply calculate the length of the path using python and use the smallest.

In fact, the length of the path can be returned by Cypher itself for all paths.
This has already been asked before, so [here is the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14104682/cypher-query-finding-all-paths-between-two-nodes-filtered-by-relationship-prope) for your reference. The accepted answer to that question is what I am talking about.

Comment: the ALL POSSIBLE PATHS option is the best yet, though it seems like it could hurt performance quite a bit in the case where the shortest 100 or more paths contain a rel or node that I want to reject.  If there were a way to tell neo4j to ignore particular rels or nodes in the search process, it seems like that would be faster, though perhaps it isn't possible.

Comment: Could you perhaps populate a quick neo4j console and share it? That'll help us actually run some queries and see what works..

Comment: added as EDIT 2 to bottom of original post.

Comment: According to the data youve populated on the console, if we assume bob and joe aren't friends, then there is no path connecting bob and joe. There IS NO path, let alone a shortest path... Could you please double check the data? Or am I missing something?

Comment: It's more like this: say the shortest path from Janet to Miles involves the rel from bob to joe.  Now assume bob and joe aren't friends...find the shortest path from Janet to Miles that doesn't have the link between bob and joe....

Comment: There is no person named 'Miles' in your sample data. Could you clarify?