# Neo4j can I make relations between relations?

Tags: neo4j, relationship, graph-databases

I'am using graph database (Neo4j) , and I need to make relations between relations , for example :

```
(user1)-[:FOLLOWED]->(user2)
```

I want to allow other users to like this activity (that user1 followed user2) , what's the best implementation for this ?

Comment: Essentially a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30520893/neo4j-db-design-edges-with-relationship-filtered-shortest-path/30534449#30534449

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Short answer:

You can't create a relation to a relation.

#### How to do?

You have to create an activity node in the middle of your relation:

```
(user1)-[:FOLLOWED]->(activity{date:..., blabla:...})-[:ACTIVITY_FOR]->(user2)
```

Then you'll be able to make another user `LIKE` this activity by creating a relation from user to activity node.

Relation names are subjectives, of course you can set your own relation names.