# Find route where all paths are of certain type and have certain property

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher

In neo4j, I need to find a route between A and every other node in my collection, where all routes have paths which are "twowheeler" (path type) and have property summer set to true.

How can I do that in neo4j database?

I tried something similar to answer from 
[THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14104682/cypher-query-finding-all-paths-between-two-nodes-filtered-by-relationship-prope) thread, but it doesn't work for me.

```
START a=node(1)
MATCH p=(a)-[r:twowheeler*..]-()
WHERE has(r.summer) and r.summer='true'
RETURN p;
```

Comment: Please, post an example of your data set and the expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `summer: true` as a property on the relationship in the match.  Something like this...

```
MATCH p=(a:Node {name: 'A'})-[r:twowheeler* {summer: true}]->()
RETURN p;
```